# Load data on demand combobox and selected item

Tags: jquery, ajax, angularjs, combobox, jqxwidgets

I am working on an Application where in a web page I have almost 20-25 comboboxes, and each one gets the data from webapi asynchronously using ajax, and once we get all the comboboxes populated, then we show the selected values  to all the comboboxes, based on the data we have in database.

In order to do that, on page load, initially I show progress bar then I use $.when(make all the ajax calls).then(hide progress bar) then bind all of them on each ajax onsuccess.

It takes long time to load all the comboboxes, and user have to wait till progress bar hides.

**Question:**
Is there any way, we only bring the data for a combobox only when user opens a combobox and till that we can show the selected value we got from database?

**for ex:** 
Lets's say we have a Country combobox on the webpage to select country and save it in database. 
First time user comes to that page, there will be no country selected, at that time, its easy to load data only when user opens the combobox, but once user selects (say United States) and click Save button, then next time user comes to that page, he wants to see 'United States' selected in that combobox. I cannot select the country ('United States') unless I load the data for the country and selects that item, and as I mentioned, for doing so, it takes long time to load and select all the comboboxes (20-25) on a page.

I want to make all the comboboxes load on demand, but I also wants to show the stored selected value in the db on the UI.

I hope I explained it little better, the whole idea is to make that page load faster and ondemand.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: You can do this pretty easily by setting cookies. Will that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

It seems a bit strange that loading of 20-25 comboboxes takes very long. Or are the options per combo a large list?
The data amount shouldn't be that large.

Anyway, you could do a request on page load where your server is returning the items with a selected item and then your angular app can populate these combos. Your server could do a db query like: `db.myCollection.find( { $where: "itemSelected != ''" } );` (MongoDB syntax) and return it as JSON.

So `checkForceLoad` is probably not the right name. It should be something like `initItems` where you load the selected items on page load from your backend.

The other combos are only populated after click.

Please have a look at the demo below (not running here --> seems like SO issue with localstorage) or in this working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/07ec4j9j/).

In the demo I've simulated the behaviour with localstorage because I don't have a backend available. Loading on combo click is delayed by a timeout to show a loading delay.

```js
angular.module('demoApp', ['LocalStorageModule'])
 .run(function($rootScope, localStorageService) {
     // init test data here because we don't have a backend
     $rootScope.modelNames = [];
     
     var data;
    
     for ( var index=0; index < 20; index++ ) {
      $rootScope.modelNames.push({name: 'test' + index});
            data = localStorageService.get('test' + index);
            if (!data) {
                localStorageService.set('test' + index, {
                    model: '',
                    options: [{
                        value: 'option-1',
                        text: 'Option 1'},
                              {
                                  value: 'option-2',
                                  text: 'Option 2'},
                              {
                                  value: 'option-3',
                                  text: 'Option 3'}]
                });
         }
        }
 })
 .config(function (localStorageServiceProvider) {
     localStorageServiceProvider
         .setPrefix('demoApp');
 })
 .factory('modelService', function($q, $timeout, localStorageService) {
  var service = {
            checkForceLoad: function(names) {
                console.log('check force load');
                // later returned from array something find().where('model' != '')
             var deferred = $q.defer(); // immediatetly resolved promise --> later $http
                var storedObj;
                
                angular.forEach(names, function(nameObj) {
                    // later just mapping required
                 storedObj = localStorageService.get(nameObj.name);
                 if (storedObj.model !== '') {
                        console.log('force', storedObj.model);
                        nameObj.forceLoad = true;
                    }
                });
                console.log('checkforce', names);
                
                //$timeout(function() {
                deferred.resolve('checked models');
                //}, 500); // simulate async
                return deferred.promise;
            },
            get: function(name) {
             var deferred = $q.defer(); // immediatetly resolved promise --> later $http
                var storedObj = localStorageService.get(name);
                $timeout(function() {
                    deferred.resolve(storedObj);
                }, 500); // simulate async
                return deferred.promise;
            },
            save: function(name, model) {
             var deferred = $q.defer(); // immediatetly resolved promise --> later $http 
                var storedData = localStorageService.get(name);
                angular.extend(storedData, {model: model});
                localStorageService.set(name, storedData);
                deferred.resolve(model);
                return deferred.promise;
            }
        };
     return service;
 })
 .directive('comboBox', function($rootScope, modelService) {
     modelService.checkForceLoad($rootScope.modelNames); // runs once
    
  return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
             modelName: '=',
                load: '='
            },
         template: '<div><select ng-model="model" ng-click="loadData()" ng-change="save(model)">'+
                '<option ng-selected="model == option.value" ng-repeat="option in options" value="{{option.value}}">{{option.text}}</option>'+
             '</select></div>',
            controller: function($scope, modelService) {
                
          $scope.save = function(model) {
                    //console.log('saving now...');
        modelService.save($scope.modelName, model)
                        .then(function(result) {
                      console.log('successfully saved', result);
                    });
       };
                $scope.loadData = function() {
                    console.log('loading data...');
                    if ( !$scope.options ) {                     
                       modelService.get($scope.modelName).then(function(result) {
                            console.log('loaded data');
                            $scope.model = result.model;
                            $scope.options = result.options;
                            //$scope.$apply();
            });
                    }
                };
                
                //console.log($scope.load);
                if ( $scope.load ) {
                    //console.log('load on start');
                    $scope.loadData();
                }
         }
        };
 })
    .controller('mainController', function ($scope, localStorageService, modelService) {
     $scope.load = true;
     console.log($scope.modelNames);
     $scope.clear = function() {
         localStorageService.clearAll();
            alert('re-run app manually');
        };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-local-storage/0.2.2/angular-local-storage.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="mainController">
    <p>Comboboxes are saved in localstorage if changed. On next run only the data with selected values will be loaded. Other combos are loaded on demand.</p>
    <button ng-click="clear()">clear localstorage (just for testing)</button>
    <combo-box model-name="nameObj.name" load="nameObj.forceLoad" ng-repeat-start="nameObj in modelNames"></combo-box>
    {{name.forceLoad}}
    <div ng-repeat-end=""></div>
</div>
```